# Neural Network for real regresion

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I have implemented a neural network to solve a problem related to audio regression (real regresion), based on multilayer perceptron. Reading the documentation, scientific articles, and some other implementations via internet, i have come to the conclusion that the multilayer perceptron is not enough for me to solve my problem, because it works well if the output is binary, but I need real output, independently if the output is in the range (0,1).

The problem is that the network does not train properly, because when I present the same example continuously, it adjusts the weights correctly in the direction of the gradient of the activation function, but when the training picks randomly the training examples, does not work well.

I Had thought to use a genetic algorithm to adjust the weights after each EPOCH of the training set to guide a little the weight adjustment of the net.

Can anyone guide me a little about it? I had also thought about using another network structure as Adaline or even if it gets ugly, try implementing a support vector machine (i prefer not to xD)

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: how do you provide random training instances, as a minibatch or one by one ?

Comment: Also what is the range of regression output.

Comment: one by one, and the regresion output would be (0,1) too. Actually, i'm not training with real audio, but doing tests with different functions as f(x) = x or f(x) = x^2

Comment: Try to feed data as minibatches like 100 instances per batch (depending on your total data size). But Keep in mind that as you reduce the number of instances per iteration, you should reduce learning rate too since the gradient steps will be more perplexed. Maybe this is why you cannot learn with one by one approach.

Comment: Ok! i will try and i'll tell you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the type of training, using the well-behaved function you mentioned (versus the complexity of audio) will not get you where you are trying to go.
   Let's start from the beginning - - what features / characteristics of the audio are you trying to capture? 
   How long are your samples, etc.?

Comment: My idea is to learn the transform that suffers the audio in particular enviroment. I have though to use a convolutional net, something similar like it is used in image recognition, and the data fed would be either the raw audio buffer or the spectogram of the signal

Comment: Not sure what you mean by suffers the audio.  What will help me to help you is to know:  (1) what is your goal?  (2) how are you sampling your audio? (3) what sort of files are you working with? (4) What characteristics of the audio are you trying to capture for the neural network to process? (5) How do you want your network to learn?  etc etc